# Equivalent to super() for functools.singledispatch

Tags: python, python-3.x, super, method-resolution-order, functools

[`functools.singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) helps to define a single-dispatch generic method.  Meanwhile, there is [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) for calling methods or accessing attributes of a superclass.

Is there something like `super()` that can be used with `singledispatch`?  I tried the following, but the result of `super(Derived, value)` is just not instance of `Base`, so it does not work as I expected:

```
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def hello(value):
    return ['default']

@hello.register(Base)
def hello_base(value):
    return hello(super(Base, value)) + ['base']

@hello.register(Derived)
def hello_derived(value):
    return hello(super(Derived, value)) + ['derived']

print(hello(Derived())
# expected ['default', 'base', 'derived'],
# but actually is ['default', 'derived'].
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that something like this will work, but I can't test it since I don't have Python 3.4 installed:

```
def getsuperclass(cls):
    try:
        nextclass = cls.__mro__[1]
    except IndexError:
        raise TypeError("No superclass")
    return nextclass

@singledispatch
def hello(value):
    return ['default']

@hello.register(Base)
def hello_base(value):
    return hello.dispatch(getsuperclass(Base))(value) + ['base']

@hello.register(Derived)
def hello_derived(value):
    return hello.dispatch(getsuperclass(Derived))(value) + ['derived']

print(hello(Derived()))
```

Note that it doesn't really make sense to call `hello` with the superclass as the argument, because if you did that you would lose the original argument (`value`) that was passed.  In your case it doesn't matter because your function doesn't use `value` at all, but a real dispatch function would probably actually do something with the value, so you need to pass the value as the argument.